# How to set doctrine associations?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I know that association property in entity is implements `\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection`. I know that in constructor such properties should be initialized:

`$this->collection = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection()`

I know that I can modify collections using `ArrayCollection#add()` and `ArrayCollection#remove()`. However I have a different case.

Suppose I have a new simple array of associative entities. Using existing methods I need to check every element in array: if entity collection has it. If no - add array element to entity collection. In addition to this, I need to check every element in entity collection. If any collection element is absent in new array, then I need to remove it from collection. So much work to do trivial thing.

What I want? To have the `setProducts` method implemented:

```
class Entity {
  private $products;

  // ... constructor

  public function setProducts(array $products)
  {
    // synchronize $products with $this->products
  }
}
```

I tried: `$this->products = new ArrayCollection($products)`. However this makes doctrine remove all products and add those ones from `$products` parameter. I want similar result but without database queries.

Is there any built in solution in Doctrine for such case?

**Edit**:
I would like to have a method in `ArrayCollection` like `fromArray` which would merge elements in collections removing unneeded. This would just duplicate using `add/remove` calls for each element in collection argumen manually.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean with "I want similar result but without database queries."? Doctrine will not perform an (insert/delete/update) query when you add/remove elements from the list. It will keep a record of the changes in the background and then compute with queries to perform once you call `flush()` on the EntityManager. If query performance is your concern, could you maybe add to the question what troubles you have with unexpected/slow queries?

Comment: @dbrumann I meant, if I use `$this->products = new ArrayCollection($products)` doctrine first remove all products then insert them again.

Comment: @dbrumann However I just noticed, that you suggested a way to do this without unneeded queries.

Comment: When you say "simple array of collections", do you mean you have an array of collections and each collection has a set of elements?

Comment: @Oli Sorry for confusion, did not notice that it was ambiguous. I edited the question. I mean a simple array of associative entities. What `ArrayCollection#toArray` returns.

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine collections do not have a "merge"-feature that will add/remove entities from an array or Collection in another Collection.

If you want to "simplify" the manual merge process you describe using add/remove, you could use `array_merge` assuming both arrays are not numeric, but instead have some kind of unique key, e.g. the entity's `spl_object_hash`:

```
public function setProducts(array $products)
{
    $this->products = new ArrayCollection(
        array_merge(
            array_combine(
                array_map('spl_object_hash', $this->products->toArray()),
                $this->products->toArray()
            ),
            array_combine(
                array_map('spl_object_hash', $products),
                $products->toArray()
            )
        )
    );
}
```

You might want to use the product id instead of `spl_object_hash` as 2 products with the same id, but created as separate entities - e.g. one through `findBy()` in Doctrine and one manually created with `new Product()` - will be recognized as 2 distinct products and might cause another insert-attempt.

Since you replace the original PersistentCollection holding your previously fetched products with a new ArrayCollection this might still result in unneeded queries or yield unexpected results when flushing the EntityManager, though. Not to mention, that this approach might be harder to read than explicitly calling addElement/removeElement on the original Collection instead.

Comment: I just tried your way. It it the same result as mine. Doctrine starts a transaction, remove all products with `DELETE FROM products_categories WHERE category_id = ?` and that insert products form method argument. Looks like Doctrine uses `$this->products` which was initialized in construtor and does not like its rewriting.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it by creating my own collection class that extends Doctrine array collection class:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class ProductCollection extends ArrayCollection
{
}
```

In the entity itself you would initialise it in the `__constructor`:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->products = new ProductCollection();
}
```

Here, Doctrine will you use your collection class for product results. After this you could add your own function to deal with your special merge, perhaps something:

```
public function mergeProducts(ProductCollection $products): ProductCollection
{
    $result = new ProductCollection();
    foreach($products as $product) {
        $add = true;
        foreach($this->getIterator() as $p) {
            if($product->getId() === $p->getId()) {
                $result->add($product);
                $add = false;
            }
        }
        if($add) {
            $result->add($product);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

It will return a brand new product collection, that you can replace your other collection in the entity. However, if the entity is attached and under doctrine control, this will render SQL at the other end, if you want to play with the entity without risking database updates you need to detach the entity:

```
$entityManager->detach($productEntity);
```

Hopes this helps

Comment: I agree that it is some kind of approach. However so much work for so trivial task? I thought Doctinre has built-in way to perform this task.

Comment: Unfortunately not